# Understanding Scala Future andThen

Tags: scala, future

I'm trying to use `andThen` method to register action stages for the future. Like this:

```
implicit val executionContext = ExecutionContext.global

val f = Future(0)
f.andThen {
  case r => println(r.get + "1")
} andThen {
  case r => println(r.get + "2")
}
```

> Since this method executes asynchronously and does not produce a
>   return value, any non-fatal exceptions thrown will be reported to the
>   ExecutionContext .

What does it mean asynchronously? It means asynchronously to the future execution itself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What does it mean asynchronously? It means asynchronously to the
>   future execution itself?

It means that the execution of `andThen` will happen on a given thread provided by the `ExecutionContext` after the originating `Future[T]` completes.

If we look at the implementation:

```
def andThen[U](pf: PartialFunction[Try[T], U])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = {
  val p = Promise[T]()
  onComplete {
    case r => try pf.applyOrElse[Try[T], Any](r, Predef.conforms[Try[T]]) finally p complete r
  }
  p.future
}
```

This method is a smart wrapper over [`Future.onComplete`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html#onComplete[U](f:scala.util.Try[T]=%3EU)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):Unit) which is a side effecting method that returns `Unit`. It applies the given function, and returns the original `Future[T]` result. As the documentation states, it is useful when you want to guarantee the order of several `onComplete` callbacks registered on the future.